# What is the need to upgrade Ubuntu? Can not install packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I don't take the software updates that my system prompts me to.

Is there any use to upgrade my system to the latest ubuntu.

The reason I ask this is that when I do `sudo apt-get update`, I see alot of Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found.

So my question is that is this 404 because I have not taken the latest ubuntu?

How exactly does this thing work, and how can I get rid of this error. I tried to install mysql, and it is giving me 404.

So I did the changes in my Sources.list

It still says: `Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com dists/restricted Sources 404  Not Found`

And some more Error on extra.ubuntu.

What should I do?

When doing `apt-get install mysql-server`, it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Why don't you take the software updates? It has security ones in there, you know. I'd take all the security I'm offered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that Ubuntu 13.4 is "End of life", see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

That means the packages are no longer available in the normal places (if you really need it, maybe elsewhere).

So you basically need to update to the current version (which is a `LTS` version, good!).

See [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: If I take ubuntu update (from 13.04 to LTS), am I going to lose my files on my HD?

Comment: Normally not - but is is always good to have a backup, and before updating, you should really make one.

Comment: So I did the changes in sources.list but I am still getting error. Please check my edits to question. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but there are quite some details to read on the answers of the linked question, and also the comments of the questions.

Comment: Yeah, I removed all other urls and kept just the old one. Thanks.

Comment: @Kraken: Ignore any errors for `extra.ubuntu.com`; they are going to error out. If the other errors are just for sources, and not for packages, you can ignore those as well. If you are also getting errors for packages, then something's wrong. Verify that you can visit [this](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/) link and that you're not using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using xubuntu 6.04 that you will eventually be unable to install new software from the software center, nor sudo apt-get. Meaning that you will be stuck with your current software.